# Why are hydathodes called hydathodes and not hydrothodes?

Tags: plant-anatomy, etymology

I can't seem to find any etymological root for the *hyda-* in *hydathode*.  I expected the water-relater structure to be called a ***hydro**thode*, but it just isn't!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about etymology and Greek language.

Comment: This *may* possibly be okay for [hsm.se] or [latin.se] but please verify in their meta/chat first. You may be asked to provide more background.

Comment: @WYSIWYG You are correct. However, those studying biology (with a similarly limited knowledge of Greek and Latin) might have a similar question when first learning about hydathodes.  Additionally, the answer given by LinuxBlanket describes the hydathode etymology as being directly related to hydathode physiology, which I think justifies its place in Biology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The etymology of hydathode, according to the [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/hydathode) dictionary, is "way (hodos) of water (hydat-)". So the correct way of dividing the word is not hyda-thode, but hydat-hode.

Also, *"hydat-"* is the genitive of the Greek word for water, *"hydor"* (literally "of water"), whereas *"hodos"* is in its nominative form ("the way"). If you want to say "water way" in ancient Greek, you have to use nominative+genitive, not nominative+nominative, but there might be also euphonic reasons to why is not *hydrohode.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are your friend.  [American heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hydathode) says "Greek hudōr, hudat-, water; see wed-1 in the Appendix of Indo-European roots + hodos, way, road."  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hydathode) says "International Scientific Vocabulary, from Greek hydat-, hydōr water + hodos road"